# fill alternate color to cell in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add background color to cell which has title and desc for multiple views div.By default I want to add purple color to title 1 and gray to desc 1 and purple to title 2 and gray to 'title 3'. now Its working well after clicked any of the title. 
 I want to fill the back ground color in on load

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.views-row-1 .contactDesc').css('display','block');
 $('.views-row-1 .contactTitle').addClass('active');
  
  $('.contactTitle').click(function(){ 
    
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
      $('.contactDesc').slideUp();
      $('.contactTitle').removeClass('active');
      $('.contactTitle').addClass('grey-bg');
      $(this).next('.contactDesc').slideDown(function(){
      $('.colorme').removeClass('grey').removeClass('purple');
          $('.colorme:visible:odd').addClass('purple');
          $('.colorme:visible:even').addClass('grey');
      });
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } 
  });
});
```

```css
.contactDesc{
  display:none;
}
.purple{
  background:purple;
}
.grey{
  background:grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
  <div class="contactTitle colorme">
     Title 1
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc colorme">
     desc 1
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
  <div class="contactTitle colorme">
     Title 2
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc colorme">
     Desc 2
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
  <div class="contactTitle colorme">
     Title 3
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc colorme">
     Desc 3
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use css?

Comment: I tried by after clicked colors get collapsed

Comment: Like Lara Belle asked, why don't you just use plain CSS, removing your coloring javascript ... and voilà! No?

Comment: Sir/Maam, don't complicate things. If it could be done in easy way. Go for it :)

Comment: simply trigger the event on your element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply trigger the click event.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.views-row-1 .contactDesc').css('display','block');
 $('.views-row-1 .contactTitle').addClass('active');
  
  $('.contactTitle').click(function(){ 
    
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
      $('.contactDesc').slideUp();
      $('.contactTitle').removeClass('active');
      $('.contactTitle').addClass('grey-bg');
      $(this).next('.contactDesc').slideDown(function(){
      $('.colorme').removeClass('grey').removeClass('purple');
          $('.colorme:visible:odd').addClass('purple');
          $('.colorme:visible:even').addClass('grey');
      });
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } 
  });
  
  $('#test').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
.contactDesc{
  display:none;
}
.purple{
  background:purple;
}
.grey{
  background:grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
  <div class="contactTitle colorme">
     Title 1
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc colorme">
     desc 1
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
  <div class="contactTitle colorme">
     Title 2
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc colorme">
     Desc 2
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
  <div id='test' class="contactTitle colorme">
     Title 3
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc colorme">
     Desc 3
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need to populate color with the javascript. You can just make it with CSS. Here is a copy of your snipet from wich i removed the jQuery coloring on.click .. and added the .contactTitle and .contactDesc classes to your coloring css sheme.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.views-row-1 .contactDesc').css('display','block');
 $('.views-row-1 .contactTitle').addClass('active');
  
  $('.contactTitle').click(function(){ 
    
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
      $('.contactDesc').slideUp();
      $('.contactTitle').removeClass('active');
      $(this).next('.contactDesc').slideDown(function(){
      });
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } 
  });
});
```

```css
.contactDesc{
  display:none;
}
.purple, .contactTitle{
  background:purple;
}
.grey, .contactDesc{
  background:grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
  <div class="contactTitle colorme">
     Title 1
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc colorme">
     desc 1
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
  <div class="contactTitle colorme">
     Title 2
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc colorme">
     Desc 2
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
  <div class="contactTitle colorme">
     Title 3
  </div> 
  <div class="contactDesc colorme">
     Desc 3
  </div> 
</div>
```